# Flask using host parameter with Blueprints (register_blueprint)

Tags: python, flask

I cannot seem to get domain matching working when registering blueprints. Referring to the [following issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/491) @miracle2k posts the following code:

```
if in_production:
    app.register_blueprint(shop, host='localhost:<port>')
    app.register_blueprint(info, host='info.localhost:<port>')
```

I tried something similar with no luck. However when I declare the `host` in my route like this:

```
@foo.route('/', host='<host>.bar.com')
...
app.register_blueprint(foo)
```

Host routing works fine. I'd much rather declare the host in the blueprint so I don't have to have the `host=` on ever single route. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Note: that in my Flask app I have delcared `app.url_map.host_matching = True`.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted in the issue you mention a [solution (gist)](https://gist.github.com/antoine-lizee/05e24078df1e3a0485bb8dafcfd0741a) that might help you, if you actually wanted your blueprints to behave as if there was no host matching (and specify only the host for the host-specific routes).

If you really need your blueprints to each have specific hosts, I would jut create a custom `Blueprint` class that inherits from the default one and behaves as you want by overriding the `add_url_rule` method:

```
class MyBlueprint(Blueprint):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default_host = kwargs.pop('default_host', None)
        Blueprint.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def add_url_rule(self, rule, endpoint=None, view_func=None, **options):
        options['host'] = options.pop('host', self.default_host)
        super().add_url_rule(self, rule, endpoint=None, view_func=None, **options)

...

shop = Blueprint(..., default_host='localhost:<port>')
info = Blueprint(..., default_host='info.localhost:<port>')
```